# Rails app crashed because of a timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crash, timeout

I have a method in my rails app that makes about a 1000 REST calls. Unfortunately, it crashed pretty quickly because of a timeout:

```
Error H12 (Request timeout) -> POST MyApp.herokuapp.com/expensiveCall dyno=web.1 queue= wait= service=30000ms status=503
```

How do I avoid this timeout? Should I be careful of anything along these lines? (Making this call is pretty costly - so looking for things I should avoid).

Thanks!

**Edit**
Also, would it be a good idea to launch a thread that would make those 1000 REST calls rather having the request wait for completion. If so, how could I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to put this into a background job of some sort. You can use something like [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job), or [resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque). Delayed Job is tool that you can use in rails to create a job that can be performed at another time, or put into a queue. Delayed Job has a fairly similar interfance in some respects to that of active record. Checkout the readme on the link there for setting it up. I've heard good things about resque which also allows you to do that, but I have no experience in using it.

Comment: Thanks for that! It just occurred to me - the calls could be made parallels. Would it be beneficial to set up delayed parallel rest requests?

Also, if I would want to scale later on - and perform my "expensiveCall" on various virtual machine instances - would you recommend to use something like reque? Thanks!

Comment: also - what would be the difference between making multiple asynchronous "expensiveJob" calls (delayed_job) vs adding these to a queue handler such as resque - or would the overall effect be the same?

Comment: to be honest, I'm not sure what's involved if you need to pass the jobs off to another machine. My experience with delayed_job has been to essentially fire off the jobs in the queue, which essentially populates the database table that you generate, and then i launch a worker process to pick them up. That worker process will keep running until I tell it otherwise, so it can always pick up another job.